# Referencing a custom counter cross-referencing

Tags: cross-referencing, latex3, custom

I created a custom reference but I want to use cross-referencing to refer to the custom reference. When I want to reference it I want it to show **`F/R 1`**, **`F/R 1.1`** or **`F/R 1.1.1`** when I cross reference the custom counter. How can I do this?

```
    \newcounter{thephase} \setcounter{thephase}{0}
\newcounter{thesubphase}[thephase] \setcounter{thesubphase}{0}
\newcounter{thesubsubphase}[thesubphase] \setcounter{thesubsubphase}{0}
\newcommand{\phase}[1]{\refstepcounter{thephase}\textbf{F/R \arabic{thephase}}}
\newcommand{\subphase}[1]{\refstepcounter{thesubphase}\textbf{F/R \arabic{thephase}.\arabic{thesubphase}}%
    }
\newcommand{\subsubphase}[1]{\refstepcounter{thesubsubphase}\textbf{F/R \arabic{thephase}.\arabic{thesubphase}.\arabic{thesubsubphase}}%
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of my interpretation of the question:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{phase}
\renewcommand*{\thephase}{F/R~\arabic{phase}}

\newcounter{subphase}[phase]
\renewcommand*{\thesubphase}{\thephase.\arabic{subphase}}

\newcounter{subsubphase}[subphase]
\renewcommand*{\thesubsubphase}{\thesubphase.\arabic{subphase}}

\newcommand*{\phase}[1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \refstepcounter{phase}%
  \label{#1}%
  \textbf{\thephase}%
}
\newcommand*{\subphase}[1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \refstepcounter{subphase}%
  \label{#1}%
  \textbf{\thesubphase}%
}
\newcommand*{\subsubphase}[1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \refstepcounter{subsubphase}%
  \label{#1}%
  \textbf{\thesubsubphase}%
}

\begin{document}

  \phase{A} First phase.

  \subphase{B} First subphase.

  \subsubphase{C} First subsubphase.

  References:
  \ref{A}, \ref{B}, \ref{C}

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

**F/R 1** First phase.
**F/R 1.1** First subphase.
**F/R 1.1.1** First subsubphase.
References: F/R 1, F/R 1.1, F/R 1.1.1

**Remarks:**

- I have simplified the counter names, they are using a different namespace as macros, thus counter `phase` and `\phase` are different entities.
- The counter have a accompanying macro `\the<counter>` that is used for the display of the counter value und its references.
- The definitions for the counter displays of `\thesubphase` and `\thesubsubphase` are simplified by using the parent counters.
- `\leavevmode` ensures that the paragraph has started to avoid that `\refstepcounter` moves to vertical mode on a previous page than the text set by `\textbf`.
- The argument of the macros is not used in the question. Maybe, it is intended for the cross-referencing label name, see the example file.
- The cross-referencing works as usual with `\label` (already present in the `\phase` macros) and `\ref` and `\pageref`.